# resolve compilation errors in maven multiple modules

Tags: maven

I am new to Maven and trying to convert an ant project to maven. I created 3 maven modules inside a master maven project:

- abc - Contains EJB and other utility code
- def - contains web code dependent on project abc
- ear - this project is to just create the ear for the above 2 including libraries.
  So far so good.

Since, project def is dependent on abc for service layer it is now giving me compilation errors. I added the dependency as follows in the def projects pom.xml shown below:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>masterProj</groupId>
    <artifactId>masterProj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>def</groupId>
  <artifactId>def</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But eclipse is still not able to resolve the compilation errors.

Comment: A `war` dependency which is defined as `compile` scope does not really make sense in Java cause a dependency in Java is usually a `jar` file. Furthermore without an full error message and some more information about your structure it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I changed it to JAR and its able to resolve the dependency now. I initially created it as a war based on the way we were packaging it using ant.